# Getting scores from a file

Tags: java, file

I am have created a word guessing game but I am having trouble with displaying the winner.

I am creating a result.txt file containing "name word attempts"

then I am reading that file and trying to determine the person with the lowest attempts.

so for example

```
Mike Keyboard 4
John Monitor 2
```

I want to display John as the winner with 2 attempts.

Some code I tried

```
     String user = null;
     int min = 0;
     int attempts=0;
     ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<>();
     File file = new File("result.txt");

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("result.txt"))) {
       while(scan.hasNext()){
         players.add(scan.nextLine());
       }  
       System.out.println(players);
    }
```

I know this didn't work but I attempted something like this as well.

```
     //System.out.println("------------Player List------------");
     /* try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("result.txt"));
        while(in.hasNext()){
           user = in.next();
           String word = in.next();
           System.out.println(user + " ");
            while (in.hasNextInt())
            {
            attempts = in.nextInt();
            }
            min = Math.min(attempts,min);
            System.out.println("User: "+user+" has " + attempts+ " attempts.");

        attempts = 0;
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it like so using Java8,

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources", "data.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    String[] winner = lines.map(l -> l.split(" "))
            .reduce((a1, a2) -> Integer.valueOf(a1[2]) < Integer.valueOf(a2[2]) ? a1 : a2)
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(winner));
}
```

Read each line of file, split it into an array and then do a reduction based on the number of attempts, keeping the one with minimum number of attempts. Then extract what you need from the result.

If you have multiple winners and want to get hold of all of them, the reduction step won't work. You may have to collect them into a `TreeMap` where key is the score and value is the name of the players with that score. Then get the first entry since that is the one with lowest score. Here's the code.

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> winners = lines.map(l -> l.split(" "))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> Integer.valueOf(a[2]), TreeMap::new, 
        Collectors.mapping(a -> a[0], Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println(winners.firstEntry());
```

Comment: if there are two winners, how can I incorporate this into the code?